# IpTables Chain not being invoked

Tags: firewall

I have added the following iptables rules but I am still seeing successful icmp, tcp, and http traffic to that subnet.

Output from iptables -L:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
REJECT     all  --  anywhere        199.22.124.0/21 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source          destination
REJECT     all  --  199.22.124.0/21 anywhere        reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Comment: You are likely to get a faster answer on [sf].

Comment: Use "-v". Are the filters attached to the correct interface, in the correct direction? Have you enabled "fast nic to nic transfers" (which bypasses the kernel network stack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that since these rules are on the router, they must be FORWARD rules, not INPUT / OUTPUT.  I'm not entirely clear how it interprets the source and destination flags, but it seems to work with -s flags.

Comment: If a packet from host A is going to host B through router C, then your forward rules on router C use the data of host A as source and host B as destination.